# Как совместить AJAX и Django

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, ajax, django

Только начал изучать jQuery и AJAX, однако застрял на самом простом примере.

По нажатию на кнопку требуется передать строку на сервер, далее выполнить конкатенацию с другой строкой, передать новую строку на клиент и вывести её с помощью `alert`. Однако строка не выводиться, вместо этого выводиться 'ошибка'.

**station_list.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#btn1").click(function () {
                var data = "station";
                $.ajax = ({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: 'task1/filter/',
                    data: {
                        'data': data
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: alert('ошибка')
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btn1">Фильтр</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from .views import List
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', List.as_view(), name='list-view'),
    url(r'^filter', views.filter),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .models import Station

def filter(request):
    if request.GET:
        data = request.GET.get("data")
        data2 = '34' + data
    return data2


class List(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'station_list.html'

    def get(self, request):
        Longitude = Station.objects.values_list("longitude", flat=True)
        Latitude = Station.objects.values_list("latitude", flat=True)
        NameStation = Station.objects.values_list("name", flat=True)
        Link = Station.objects.values_list("link", flat=True)
        ctx = {
            'Longitude': Longitude, 'Latitude': Latitude, 'NameStation': NameStation, 'Link': Link
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)
```

Как мне кажется если напротив error или success добавить функцию, то она вообще не будет срабатывать. То есть, если написать:

`error: function() {
   alert('ошибка');
}`

ничего не сработает.
Но если написать так:
`error: alert('ошибка');`
то всё сработает. Никак не могу понять в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить более полезный обработчик ошибки

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

и посмотреть в консоли, какая именно ошибка возникает.

Comment: Добавил, но в консоли всё чисто. Пишет No errors

Comment: Значит ошибка не возникает.

Comment: Не сразу заметил, вы вместо вызова функции `ajax` присваиваете ей объект зачем-то.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь хотя бы ясна ошибка: jquery-1.10.1.min.js:6 GET http://localhost:8000/task1/filter/?data=station 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Скорее всего, это из-за относительного URL. Добавьте слэш вначале `url: '/task1/filter/',`

Comment: Добавлял уже, все равно появляется та же ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Исправил следующие ошибки в коде:

1) В представление неправильно был указан `url`

```
    $(function () {
        $("#btn1").click(function () {
            var data = "station";
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: '/map/filter/', //Здесь была ошибка
                data: {
                    'data': data
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            })
```

2) Во views.py надо изменить метод filter следующим образом

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.http import HttpResponse

data2 = ''

def filter(request):
    if request.GET:
        data = request.GET.get('data')
        data2 = data
    return HttpResponse(data2+'3')
```